# Authorization: Key for Push Notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Where can i find the API for Authorization: key for Push Notifications in iOS?

This is Android Authorization key., like this where can i find iOS Authorization key?

```
'Authorization: key=' . ANDROID_API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Comment: i dont thing you need any key for push notification in ios https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started . Go through this link

Comment: Push notification compared to android is completely different in iOS, you can refer to this article  https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/

Comment: we can put this key in php code., i think we can get this key from iTunesConnect., but not sure where can i find that key in iTunesConnect @chiragshah

Comment: I am done my push notifications through appcoda @vinaykrishnan., but we have to give that authorization key at the back end i think.

Comment: So i suppose that you have enabled push notifications for you applications. And if everything goes well you will get a device token in App Delegate class method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, and you can use the same in PHP code to send push

Comment: I am checked with that Device Token @Vinaykrishnan., The response I got from the server like notification sent successful with registered mobile number., but i'm not getting the notification in my phone..

Comment: Please verify this points 1) Make sure your app id and certificate is valid. 2) Please check your provisioning profile or your Xcode project is using the wrong profile/certificate 3).p12 is missing the certificate or the key.

Comment: You can also use pusher app to test the push notifications without any php code https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

Comment: My Code is in Objective-C and the pusher is showing Swift code., It is not working properly. Is there any other tool to test the Push Notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Remote push notifications to iOS devices do not require an HTTP Authorization header. [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1):

> The APNs provider API lets you send remote notification requests to APNs. APNs then conveys notifications to your app on iOS, tvOS, and macOS devices, and to Apple Watch via iOS.
>
> The provider API is based on the HTTP/2 network protocol. Each interaction starts with a POST request, from your provider, that contains a JSON payload and a device token. APNs forwards the notification payload to your app on the specific user device identified by the request’s included device token.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/weirdindiankid/bb5a7011fce50bee3d8b03de642039e2) a simple Python script that can help send push notifications. You will need a certificate and key before you can use this script. To get these (and to get a better overview of push notifications on iOS in general), check out:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1